# After moving my Windows Store App project I can't compile it because .resw not found

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a Problem with a Windows Store App.

I moved the folder and now I cant compile it, I get the error:

```
Fehler  2   File C:\[old path]\Strings\en-US\Resources.resw not found.  C:\[new path]\MakePRI
```

I dont know how to fix it because the app is in the same relative path in the project as before.

any hints for a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This item was probably added to the project with absolute path. You can fix that in one of two ways:

- In `SolutionExplorer` remove `Resources.resw` from the project. Then click on `Show All Files` icon to make the file appear in its folder although it's not included in the project (I understand you did copy it over when moving the project). Now right click on the file and select `Include In Project`. After that you can again turn off `Show All Files`.
- In `Solution Explorer` right click on the project and select `Unload Project`. Now right click on the project again and select `Edit ProjectName.csproj`. In the file find `Resources.resw` and replace the existing tag (and any subtags) with `<PRIResource Include="Strings\en-US\Resources.resw" />`. Save the changes and close the file. Right click on the project again and select `Reload Project`.

Answer (score 0):

I got into this problem and I found an easy solution. Open the project and it will show the error. Now right click on the App name in Solution Explorer (on the right hand side) and select Build.This will set the path again and the project can be run now.